# Как RSS на сайт импортировать?

Tags: html, javascript, php

Есть RSS лента сайта, надо на наш сайт в код запихать скрипт, чтобы все новости с RSS того были у нас на сайте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два варината.
Первый:

1. парсите RSS-ленту;
2. добавляете данные из п.1 к Вам в БД (или откуда у Вас берутся новости?);
3. новости показываются у Вас на сайте.

Второй:

1. парсите RSS-ленту;
2. сразу отображаете её у себя на сайте, минуя БД. То есть, подгружаете
       js-скрипт, который рисует новости.

Решения "поставил один скрипт и готово" нет. Хотя для каких-нибудь CMS можно найти.

Comment: Сам использую первый вариант, парсинг по крону, чтобы загрузка страницы не зависела от источника rss.

Answer (score 0):

RSS-лента - это просто XML и работать можно с ней, как с обычным HTML. Для отображения можно использовать template jQuery. Для удобства можно чтоб на PHP возвращал JSON и дальше js с ним работает, тогда еще проще и не надо никакого XML.

Answer (score 0):

http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=32&id=1119

делай нихочу.

правильно. RSSхороший, это обычная XML